# Mathematica can't solve DSolve[{f[0] ==d,f'[0]==v0,f''[t] == -g*m2/f[t]^2}, f, t]?

Tags: differential-equations

```
In[11]:= $Version                                                               

Out[11]= 9.0 for Linux x86 (32-bit) (November 20, 2012)

In[12]:= DSolve[{f[0] == d, f'[0] == v0, f''[t] == g*m2/f[t]^2}, f, t]             

DSolve::bvimp: General solution contains implicit solutions. In the boundary
    value problem these solutions will be ignored, so some of the solutions will
    be lost.

Out[12]= {}
```

The code above pretty much says it all. I get the same error if I replace `g*m2` with `1`.

This seems like a really simple DFQ to solve. I'd like to tell DSolve to assume all variables are real and that d, g, and m2 are all greater than 0, but there's unfortunately no way to do that.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying for a symbolic solution. And unfortunately, symbolic integration is hard (while symbolic differentiation is easy).

The way this integration works is to obtain the energy functional by integrating once

```
E = 1/2*f'[t]^2 + C/f[t]
```

and then to isolate `f'[t]`. The resulting integral is not easy to solve and leads to the mentioned implicit solutions.

---

Did you really want to get the symbolic solution or only some function table to plot the solutions or compute other related quantities?

---

Since it was clarified that the requested quantity is the maximum of certain solutions: This can be computed by setting `v=0` in the energy equation

```
C/x = E = 1/2*v0^2 + C/x0
```

or

```
x = C*x0/(C + 1/2*v0^2*x0 )
```

One would have to analyze the time aspect to make sure that this extremum is reached before passing again at the initial point `x0`.

Comment: I've already used NDSolve to draw graphs, but was hoping DSolve could help me find some minimal values and allow me to analyze the solution further.

Comment: You are describing a straight shot into the sun. Or away from it. There will be no (non-trivial) minimal values. Try the 2D or 3D formulation, the trajectories are cone sections, but the time parametrization is still something that is not symbolically representable.

Comment: Oh, to clarify: if you shoot away from the Sun at less than escape velocity, your rocket will reach a maximal distance before turning back around. I'm trying to find this maximal distance as a function of initial position and velocity.

Comment: That is simple, just set `f'[t]==0` in the energy equation. The energy derives from the initial conditions.